# Have a select query with multiple where clauses return multiple result rows in one result table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I have a query such as:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS user_list FROM tbl_users
WHERE (enrolled = 1 AND age >=15 AND age < 20)
OR (enrolled = 1 AND age >=20 AND age < 25)
OR (enrolled = 1 AND age >=25 AND age < 30)
OR (enrolled = 1 AND age >=30)
```

How can I have it return a result for each where condition in one row and one table as such:

```
user_list
---------
   18    --(enrolled = 1 AND age >=15 AND age < 20)
   12    --(enrolled = 1 AND age >=20 AND age < 25)
   22    --(enrolled = 1 AND age >=25 AND age < 30) 
   56    --(enrolled = 1 AND age >=30)
```

Comment: This is just a simple example of my problem, I will likely to have hundreds/ thousands of where clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been mentioned you can use a case and perform this all in one query, however you don't need to use a subquery, although I am not a massive fan of it, MySQL allows you to use column aliases in the group by, so the following will work:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN (enrolled = 1 AND age >=15 AND age < 20) THEN '15-19'
            WHEN (enrolled = 1 AND age >=20 AND age < 25) THEN '20-24'
            WHEN (enrolled = 1 AND age >=25 AND age < 30) THEN '25-29'
            WHEN (enrolled = 1 AND age >=30) THEN '30+'
            ELSE 'Other'
        END AS AgeRange 
        COUNT(id) AS user_list 
FROM    tbl_users
WHERE   Enrolled = 1
AND     Age >= 15
GROUP BY AgeRange;
```

*Note, I have still added a where clause to avoid scanning redunant data.*

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3cef9/1)**

This falls down however if you have missing data, e.g. an empty table will return, not this:

```
AGERANGE    USER_LIST
15-19       0
20-24       0
25-29       0
30+         0
```

As you might expect. To get around this I would create a pseudo table to select from, and left join your data:

```
SELECT  t.Name AS Age_Range,
        COUNT(u.ID) AS User_List
FROM    (   SELECT  '15-19' AS Name, 15 AS LowerBound, 20 AS UpperBound, 1 AS Enrolled
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  '20-24' AS Name, 20 AS LowerBound, 25 AS UpperBound, 1 AS Enrolled
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  '25-29' AS Name, 25 AS LowerBound, 30 AS UpperBound, 1 AS Enrolled
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  '30+' AS Name, 30 AS LowerBound, 9999999 AS UpperBound, 1 AS Enrolled
        ) t
        LEFT JOIN tbl_Users u
            ON u.Enrolled = t.enrolled
            AND u.Age >= t.LowerBound
            AND u.Age < t.UpperBound
GROUP BY t.Name;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2d5f/1)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this method

```
create table t (list1 int,list2 int,list3 int,list4 int)

insert into t
SELECT 
SUM(case when age >=15 AND age < 20 then 1 else 0 end) AS user_list1,
SUM(case when age >=20 AND age < 25 then 1 else 0 end) AS user_list2,
SUM(case when age >=25 AND age < 30 then 1 else 0 end) AS user_list3,
SUM(case when age >=15 AND age < 20 then 1 else 0 end) AS user_list4
FROM tbl_users
WHERE enrolled = 1 ;

select list1 from t union all
select list2 from t union all
select list3 from t union all
select list4 from t
```

Comment: I am trying to use this however I get this error:    Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare @t table (list1 int,list2 int)

insert into @t
SELECT 
SUM(case when' at line 1.  Should the table be already created?

Comment: 1 queries executed, 0 success, 1 errors, 0 warnings

Query: declare @t table (list1 int,list2 int) insert into @t SELECT SUM(case when ((start_time >= '2013-08-02 00:00:15' AND start_time ...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare @t table (list1 int,list2 int)

insert into @t
SELECT 
SUM(case when' at line 1

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0 sec

Answer (score 0):

There are the following SQL clauses that could help:

`Group by`, `Case`, and `Subqueries`...look them up and play with that, should be fun to figure it out yourself...

You could look into having another column in your query (e.g. case between 15 and 18 then 1,  case ... then 2, ...) as Range, identifying a range and grouping by that...

This is an example of how to identify your ranges as columns in a subquery, and query on top of that grouped by the ranges in your subquery:

```
select count(*) as Count, r as Range 
    from 
        (select 
        (case 
        when enrolled = 1 AND age >=20 AND age < 25 then 'r1' 
        when enrolled = 1 AND age >=25 AND age < 30 then 'r2' 
        end) as r 
        from Text)          
    as groups 
group by r
```

This results in the following:

Range | Count

r1        |  10

r2    |  7

where r1 can be your range corresponding to "enrolled = 1 AND age >=20 AND age < 25" or so on, defined in the case clause.

Comment: Thanks, could you please give me a brief example of this as I dont quite understand.

Answer (score 0):

U could use unions:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS user_list
  FROM tbl_users
 WHERE (enrolled = 1 AND age >= 15 AND age < 20)
union
SELECT COUNT(id)
  FROM tbl_users
 where (enrolled = 1 AND age >= 20 AND age < 25)
union
SELECT COUNT(id)
  FROM tbl_users
 where (enrolled = 1 AND age >= 25 AND age < 30)
union
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_users where (enrolled = 1 AND age >= 30)
```

Comment: I want to avoid using UNION as this would cause the query to run a lot of times which will make it slow

Comment: This is not always the case. Combining multiple where clauses with lots of `OR`s can essentially scramble the execution plan, so 4 seperate queries may each be able to take advantage of an index, combining the clauses can result in a table scan. It all depends on the complexity and width of your data. Unfortunately only you can answer this by testing both methods and checking the plans.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be problem for performance to use 4 simple queries instead of one complicated

Answer (score 0):

this is simple

`select count(1),ceil(age/5)*5 from tbl_users where enrolled=1 group by ceil(age/5)`